# Is the ABC-partition problem NP-hard?

Tags: reductions, partitions

In the **ABC-partition problem**, there are three sets $A, B, C$ with $m$ positive integers in each. The sum of all integers is $m T$. The goal is to construct $m$ triplets with the same sum $T$, each of which contains exactly one integer from $A, B$ and $C$.

The problem "feels" NP-hard, but I could not find a proof for this. I could only find reductions in the wrong direction:

- Reduction from ABC-partition to [3-partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) is easy: replace each $a \in A$ with $8a+1$, each $b \in B$ with $8b+2$, and each $c \in C$ with $8c+4$. This forces the 3-partition oracle to construct with exactly one item from each of $A$, $B$ and $C$.
- Reduction from ABC-partition to [3-dimensional matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching) is easy too: keep the items in $A, B, C$ as they are, and add a hyperedge $\{a,b,c\}$ iff $a+b+c = T$.
- I also found [a reduction from 3-dimensional matching to ABCD-partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem#Reduction_from_3d-matching_to_ABCD-partition), which is similar to ABC-partition but with four sets; and [a reduction from 4-partition to 3-partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem#Reduction_from_4-partition_to_3-partition).

But, none of these reductions shows that ABC-partition is NP hard.

Previously I asked specifically about a reduction from 3-partition from ABC-partition; now I am not even sure if it is NP-hard. Is it?

Comment: I don't know of a reduction from 3-partition to ABC-partition. But ABC-partition is straightforwardly a special case of 3-dimensional matching (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching), and I think that would make a better source problem to attempt a reduction from.

Comment: Show that ABC-partition is NP-hard by reduction from any NP-hard problem, then use the Cook–Levin theorem to obtain a reduction from 3-partition to ABC-partition.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus these problems seem so similar, that I thought there may be a more direct reduction.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're interested in such a reduction?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus My personal interest is mainly theoretic and educational. But there may be a practical application for approximation algorithms: if you have an approximation algorithm for one problem, then you can use the reduction to get an approximation algorithm for the other. I think it does not follow directly from the fact that both are NP-hard.

Comment: @j_random_hacker what is a reduction from 3-dimensional matching to ABC-partition? I tried to find one, but found it hard to assign values to numbers in the ABC-partition instance such that only edges from the hypergraph have the correct sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find the proof claimed by Garey and Johnson at [SP16]. But I found two other proofs, which seem independent (do not rely on the existing proof):

- [Yu, Hoogeveen and Lenstra (2004)](https://doi.org/10.1023/B:JOSH.0000036858.59787.c2)
- [Caracciolo, Fichera, and Sportiello (2006)](https://doi.org/10.1023/B:JOSH.0000036858.59787.c2)

Comment: This answered the question, it can be marked accepted. It is a follow up to Steven's partial answer 3-week prior.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the [Numerical 3D matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_3-dimensional_matching). Wikipedia cites a proof of NP-Hardness by Garey and Johnson (problem SP16).

Comment: Thanks! I looked at the book. They claim that it is NP-hard by transformation from 3-d matching, but do not provide a proof; they refer to their 1975 article here: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0204035  but in that article, I did not find any mention of numerical 3-dimensional matching. There is only a reduction from 3-d matching to some job scheduling problem (scheduling jobs on 5 processors with 8 resources; later reduced to scheduling on 3 processors with 1 resource).